# Connecting R and Redshift via dplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, amazon-redshift

I am willing to use data from R which is stored in Redshift. I have no problems connecting via the redshift package:

```
library(redshift)
conn_redshift   <- redshift.connect("jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname",
                                user,
                                password)

table_Names     <- redshift.tables(conn_redshift)$table_name
```

This works fine. However, I am a fan of the dplyr interface, but I have problems to connect via src_postgres. Therefor I first tried to create a local database, this is working as well:

```
library(dplyr)
connection <- src_postgres(dbname, user,password, host = "localhost")
```

However, when I add the Redshift credentials

```
myRedshift2 <- src_postgres(dbname, host ,port, user,password)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect ... on dbname)
```

Since I am able to connect to a postgres database locally it seems that it can not be an installation/driver problem and since I can connect to redshift via another package, it seems that it can not be a permission (IP filter) problem. The code that I have written is working on a colleagues laptop as well, so it shouldn't be code problem neither. We have compared sessionInfo(), but that is exactly the same. Does anyone have another possible idea?

Comment: I used to connect to Redshift using the RPostgreSQL package. I believe this is the package dplyr loads for its Postgres interface. You could do more direct troubleshooting with that, I think.

Comment: That is correct, I am trying there already for a while, but since I am able to connect with localhost, it is hard for me to identify correctly where it is going wrong. Underneath this is even using dbConnect of package DBI.

Comment: You may have seen this already, but in case you have not: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G8828SPGX3PK/Connecting-R-with-Amazon-Redshift

It provides a good example of connecting with dplyr and describes where you can find all the info you need for the `src_postgres()` arguments. It must be the host specification if you are successful with localhost. The AWS host URL is a little strange. The link has a good example of one, just to be sure you are passing the correct info.

Comment: That's where I got the idea from to go for the dplyr interface. We've set this up, and the code that I am using is working on my colleagues laptop, but not on mine.

Comment: If the same code is not working across two separate machines, then my ability to help is limited. I have worked with Redshift and R in the past so I thought I would try to provide some guidance. Sorry it was not all that useful. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway, I am already glad that someone wants to think along.